# how to create a register that changes due to a for loop - assembly

Tags: assembly

I have a simple for loop that I am working on translating from c++ to Assembly. 
The code needed to translate is...

```
int w1 = 40;   
int w2 = 20;   
int total;     
int result[4]; 
total = w1;

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    total = total + w2;
    if (total > 100) {
        total = total - 100;
    }
}
```

I am asked to create a register for int total. However, because it is constantly changing throughout the loop, I am unsure how to do this.

Comment: This isn't a site for people to do your homework for you.

Comment: *what* assembly of *what* CPU on *what* platform?

Comment: Creating a register makes no sense, the registers already exist within the CPU. I think you are being asked to keep the value of total in a register, so it can be read or modified without going to RAM.

Answer (score 0):

All processor are designed with a specific purpose and there are registers and mechanisms oriented to that particular purpose. In the case of x86/x86-64 which are (*Intel/AMD*) based chips, CL/CX/ECX/RCX are the best choice whenever you need to count. As an example;

```
L1:    add     eax, 175
       loop    L1
```

This will add 175 to EAX, ECX times.

```
       rep     movsq
```

This would move qwords from DS:ESI to ES:DSI, ECX times. or;

```
L1:    lodsw
       cmp     ax, 0x3113
       loopnz  L1
```

This reads a word from memory pointed to by DS:ESI and compares it with 0x3113 and if equal or ECX becomes zero, loop will terminate.

Comment: Why does `lods` read a word, when you don't specify size? I thought the default was byte (anyway, I always wrote the size suffix like `lodsw`, in my sources).

Comment: @Tommylee2k in this particular example it doesn't matter as the point is to demonstrate how a word can be read from memory, compared to something and the loop be sensitive to both EAX & ECX.

Comment: @Ped7g when I was making sure the example worked, GDB strips the qualifier, and I was focusing on congruency of answer without actually writing complete code. But yes, in NASM if one doesn't suffix with B, W, D, Q the opcode will just simply be ignored. If I remember correctly, FASM assumes words without a qualifier, but I may be mistaken on that.

Comment: @Shift_Left you're right, still I’m always alerted if I see lods & co without setting/resetting the direction flag, since it once took me hours to find my bug of forgetting it ;-)

Comment: @Tommylee2k so far of the 60k lines of code I've got in assembly, assuming increment has worked for me.  Only when decrementing is required will I set the flag, but just before, I'll push flags and then restore when I'm done in case DF was already set. If stack won't work `LAHF` & `SAHF` are options too, but most often AH has to be moved somewhere else.

Comment: @Shift_Left can't test gdb right now, but in such case usually the argument is present? Like `lods ax` or `lods ax,[ds:si]`? Ie. it's still possible to deduct the size of operation even from gdb syntax. Anyway, the OP didn't even specify the platform, nor Assembly dialect, he's probably not even aware of all those subtle differences... :)

Comment: @Ped7g as a matter of fact, GDB avoids any ambiguity with `lods    ax, WORD PTR ds:[rsi]`. You make a good point on what OP omitted and on that note, when a question is so ambiguous, maybe it should be avoided all together.

Comment: @Tommylee2k: the System V ABI for x86 and x86-64 requires the DF is cleared (increment mode) on function call / return, just like it requires the x87 stack to be empty (or a return value in st(0)), and for the x87 unit to be in x87 mode, not MMX mode.  I assume the Windows calling conventions are the same.  If you're writing a bootloader, you're absolutely right that you shouldn't assume anything about DF, but in "normal" 32 or 64-bit user-space code, CLD is usually a waste of an instruction.

Comment: [LOOP is slow; I wouldn't recommend it](stackoverflow.com/questions/35742570/why-is-the-loop-instruction-slow-couldnt-intel-have-implemented-it-efficiently).  ECX is only special for REP and LOOP (and shift counts), so usually there's no reason other than human-readability to prefer it for loop counters.  Your statement that it's the best for counting is way too strong.